# Hibernate throws nullpointerexception

Tags: hibernate

I'm getting a NPE which I don't know how, I've looked around on google and can't seem to find a decent answer, anyone who can help me out pls.
The CustomerDaoImpl line the stacktrace is pointing to is:

```
return (CustomerPerk)this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(CustomerPerk.class, customerPerkPk);


java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.isEqual(EntityType.java:344)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.isEqual(ComponentType.java:172)
at org.hibernate.engine.EntityKey.equals(EntityKey.java:119)
at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:305)
at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.getEntity(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:368)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityUsingInterceptor(SessionImpl.java:656)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromSessionCache(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:533)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:440)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1005)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:998)
at com.perkinator.dao.CustomerPerkDaoImpl.getCustomerPerk(CustomerPerkDaoImpl.java:32)
at com.perkinator.service.CustomerServiceImpl.addPerkAmount(CustomerServiceImpl.java:169)
```

The CustomerPerk Mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_perk")
public class CustomerPerk {

@Id
private CustomerPerkPk customerPerkPK = new CustomerPerkPk();

@Column
private BigDecimal amountSpent;

@Column
private int timesVisited;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Column(name="customer_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private int customer;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Column(name = "perk_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private int perk;
```

And the CustomerPerkPk

```
@Embeddable
public class CustomerPerkPk implements Serializable {

@ManyToOne
private Customer customer;

@ManyToOne
private Perk perk;
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the `CustomerPerk` Entity mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is `@EmbeddedId` rather than `@Id` 
See [2.2.3.2.1. @EmbeddedId property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/)